# Font features with OpenType/Graphite font

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to access [these](http://software.sil.org/padauk/wp-content/uploads/sites/39/2016/06/Padauk-features.pdf) font features, but I can't manage to get things to work. It's been a long day and there's a good chance I'm just missing something simple. Adding the options in the preamble with fontspec didn't work, adding them in the `\setmainfont` command didn't work, and even adding a local `\fontspec` to test isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example how to activate the `Tear drop style washwe` (the sffamily shows for comparision the same without the feature):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Padauk}[Renderer=Graphite,RawFeature={Tear drop style washwe=True}]
\setsansfont{Padauk}
\begin{document}
ရက်နေ့တွင် 

\sffamily
ရက်နေ့တွင် 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This still wasn't working for me until I removed the ```Script=Myanmar``` option. Do you know why this would matter? It's still Myanmar script haha. Did I not need the script option in the first place?

Comment: well the fontspec documentation says that graphite options can only be set with RawFeature. If you want to set a language, try e.g. `RawFeature={language=kyu}` which activates the tear drop too.

Comment: Right. The difference between your sample code and what I had was the script option. Once I removed that everything seems to be working. Which makes the script option seem a bit superfluous to me. But if everything's working, then I shouldn't complain! Appreciate your help!